# How Can I refresh the information of my website in Google?

Tags: html, google-search

I recently update my website:

http://luscoefusco13.es

But it appears in the Google search with the old attributes.

How Can I change the name and the description of the website?.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask Google to re-crawl your URLs.
That could help you:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, kpc, just a final question, How much time they need to refresh the website?.

Comment: Usually It takes up to 48h

Comment: Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being a ridiculous question, I'll answer it.

There is no 'refresh Google results' button, you have to wait for Google to crawl your website, see the changes and update their version of your website.

You can however, submit a sitemap to Google via [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters) and you can [submit your URL to Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url).

Comment: Hi, first of all many thanks to kpc and Tom, to anwer the questions. Do I need a meta tag to change the names?, I have three files uploaded in the website, index.html, main.html and top.html. Please, Can you take a look and answer?. Thanks.

Comment: Please do some basic SEO research before asking basic questions here.

Comment: Ok, I will search.